# Does GarbageCollectorMXBean#getCollectionTime() indicate time JVM was *paused* for GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jmx

The documentation on [`GarbageCollectorMXBean.html#getCollectionTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html#getCollectionTime--) is sparse.

It says:

> Returns the approximate accumulated collection elapsed time in milliseconds. This method returns -1 if the collection elapsed time is undefined for this collector.
>
> The Java virtual machine implementation may use a high resolution timer to measure the elapsed time. This method may return the same value even if the collection count has been incremented if the collection elapsed time is very short.

What I'm trying to understand is whether this "accumulated collection elapsed time" is real time that the JVM is paused during for (which is an easy to understand concept) or whether it means something vaguer.

Answer (score 1):

No. It means the time it took to collect the garbage. It doesn't tell anything about how long (if at all, depending on the GC algorithm being used) the JVM was paused during that time.

You can use that information to calculate average collection times, which gives you an idea about how much garbage is being generated.

You can compare the values from the MXBean to the accurate statistics generated by for example [jstat](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/how-to-monitor-java-garbage-collection) or just regular `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`.

Comment: are you able to point to a reference for this (code, documentation, somebody who works on the JVM)? How do you know this?

Comment: Stop the world collection is something that most recent GC algorithms try to avoid. You can easily test it yourself by running a simple program that uses a parallel gc algorithm and generates a moderate amount of garbage. Even though the JVM is never stopped, you'll still be able to see that collections occur.

Comment: but how do I know if the JVM pauses or not if it's for an imperceptibly short time? Apologies for my ignorance, but my understanding was that even the in-parallel GC algorithms do work in parallel (such as scanning for garbage) but they actually pause to sweep. Has that changed?

Comment: You don't get that information from the MXBean. As you can see it's not exactly a very sophisticated tool, giving you 2 numbers for such a complicated operation. I'd say forget about the whole bean.

Comment: That sounds like pretty sage advice ;)

Comment: @Kayaman Is there anything better for an internal use? I'd like the information to be logged together.

Comment: @maaartinus The next step would probably be [JVMTI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/), but that goes beyond my expertise.